# Xamarin grid and StackLayout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, grid, xamarin.forms

I would like to know how to put a stacklayout into a grid case of xamarin forms and repeat tha pattern.

I decleare in my xaml my grid and the stacklayout.

```
        <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <StackLayout x:Name="MyLayout">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```

Then in my c# i wannt to create

```
            var test = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product() {Desc = "DESC", Brand= "HelloWorld", Price= "30", Uri = "UriToPicture" },
             new Product() {Desc = "DESC2", Brand= "HelloWorld2", Price= "30", Uri = "UriToPicture" }

        };


        Image PicProd = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
        PicProd.Source = FileImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(test[0].Uri));
        Label Name= new Label { Text = test[0].Marque.ToString(), TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
        Label Desc = new Label { Text = test[0].Desc.ToString(), TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
        Label Price = new Label { Text = test[0].Prix.ToString(), TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };


        MyLayout.Children.Add(PicProd);
        MyLayout.Children.Add(Name);
        MyLayout.Children.Add(Desc);
        MyLayout.Children.Add(Price);

        MyGrid.Children.Add(MyLayout, 0, 0);
        MyGrid.Children.Add(MyLayout, 0, 1);

        Content = MyGrid;
```

So I have two stacklayout elements that i want to display on two colomns(side by side) but i don't succed to display them correctly

Comment: for information in the future i want to iterate on my product list to display them in my grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` on elements to position them inside the grid. These are 0-based indexers. So in your case you could set the StackLayout as follows:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MyLayout" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
```

And in the next you could put:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MyLayout" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
```

**UPDATE:**

You cannot add the same instance of a control to a page twice, which is why only one of your items is showing up. You should instantiate 2 actual instances of your `StackLayout`. Remove the `StackLayout` from your XAML and declare it in code-behind. Then create 2 separate label instances and add those to the appropriate `StackLayout`. It should look something like this:

```
var test = new List<Product>
{
    new Product() {Text1 = "DESC", Text2= "HelloWorld" },
    new Product() {Text1 = "DESC2", Text2= "HelloWorld2" }
};

MyGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;

var Name = new Label { Text = test[0].Text1.ToString(), TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
var Desc = new Label { Text = test[0].Text2.ToString(), TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };

var MyLayout = new StackLayout();
MyLayout.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
MyLayout.Children.Add(Name);
MyLayout.Children.Add(Desc);
MyGrid.Children.Add(MyLayout, 0, 0);

var Name2 = new Label { Text = test[0].Text1.ToString(), TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };
var Desc2 = new Label { Text = test[0].Text2.ToString(), TextColor = Color.Black, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };

var MyLayout2 = new StackLayout();
MyLayout2.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
MyLayout2.Children.Add(Name2);
MyLayout2.Children.Add(Desc2);
MyGrid.Children.Add(MyLayout2, 1, 0);
```

Another thing to keep in mind, the parameters for the `Children.Add` call want the column as the first parameter and then the row. Additionally you could use this extension method to simplify the process of adding children with spans etc.

```
public static class GridExtension
{
    public static void AddChild(this Grid grid, View view, int row, int column, int rowspan = 1, int columnspan = 1)
    {
        if (row < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row));
        if (column < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(column));
        if (rowspan <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(rowspan));
        if (columnspan <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(columnspan));
        if (view == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(view));

        Grid.SetRow((BindableObject)view, row);
        Grid.SetRowSpan((BindableObject)view, rowspan);
        Grid.SetColumn((BindableObject)view, column);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan((BindableObject)view, columnspan);

        grid.Children.Add(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already use  "MyGrid.Children.Add(MyLayout, 0, 0)" witch add my layout in the top left case. and then I repeat the operation with  MyGrid.Children.Add(MyLayout, 0, 1); to put antoher object stack in my colomn 1

Comment: What doesn't work then? One thing I notice is that you're adding the exact same instance of MyLayout to both columns so if you're expecting their values to differ this won't work.

Comment: yeah, i know this is juste for my test. But I don't know why I doesn't work! it should put my stacklayout on two different colomns but I don't

Comment: Thank you. it works. It was that. the double use of the same stack. In my iteration i have to declare a new stacklayout everytime and that works great.

Answer (score 0):

> So I have two `Stacklayout` elements that i want to display on two colomns(side by side) but i don't succed to display them correctly

The problem is that you don't have two `Stacklayout` elements. Instead, you have one single instance that you pass two times to the grid using `Add` method.

If you want a second `Stacklayout` side by side, first create a new instance of a `Stacklayout` either in code or in XAML:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MySecondLayout">
      <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
      </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

And pass it to your grid using `Add` method:

```
 //... Populate "MySecondLayout" as you did for "MyLayout" 

 // Add your two layouts to the grid
 MyGrid.Children.Add(MyLayout, 0, 0);
 MyGrid.Children.Add(MySecondLayout, 0, 1);
```

If you want to use the exact same `Stacklayout` twice side by side, you must create two different instances of a `Stacklayout`.